# Where have you seen this topological ring used?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and define the topology on $R$ to be that where the open sets are unions of ideals.  Then this forms a topological ring - let me know if you need proof.  Have you seen it used anywhere or what can you do with it now that you know it's a topological ring?

*Claim 1*. The unions of ideals forms a topology on $R. \ $

*Proof*.
$R$ itself and $\varnothing$ are both unions of ideals, $\varnothing$ considered as the empty union.  Let $I = \bigcup I_i$ and $J = \bigcup J_i$, be unions of ideals.  Then $I \cap J =\bigcup_{i,j} I_i \cap J_j$.  Prove that as an exercise.  Since an arbitrary union of an arbitrary union is an arbitrary union, we're done.

*Claim 2*. The multiplication map on $R\times 2$, $(x,y) \mapsto xy$ is continuous.  Note that since ideals form a basis for the topology, for this particular problem (inverse function image), it suffices to consider the inverse image of a single ideal and prove that it's a union of ideals in $R\times R$.  As the inverse image of any open set would then be a union of ideals in $R\times 2$, or open.  But are open sets in $R\times R$ ideals? It turns out that they are...

*Claim 3*.  The product topology of $R\times r$ induced by the unions of ideals topology of $R$, coincides with the unions of ideals topology of the ring $R\times R$.    As an exercise prove that the ideals of $R\times R$ are of the form $I \times J$ for ideals $I,J$ in $R$.

*Proof*.  We can come up with an identity for $(\bigcup I_i )\times (\bigcup J_i)$, namely that it equals $\bigcup (I_i \times J_j)$.  So by definition of product topology a basis for the product topology is the set of all $U\times V$ where $U,V$ are both unions of ideals of $R$.  Then an open set in $R\times R$ is the same thing as a union of ideals of $R\times R$ as we've shown that ideals are of that form.

*Proof of Claim 2*.

Comment: I "need proof", since I've convinced myself that every [non-trivia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_ring)l s[imple ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring) is a counter-example. $\hspace{.63 in}$

Comment: How would that be a counter example, @RickyDemer? In that case you'd get a very boding topological ring: only it and the empty space are open. Still fine, though...

Comment: We also need addition to be continuous, and this is where Marie's answer applies.

Comment: Just to emphasize, having a ring and a topology on its set of elements does not make a topological ring. To be a topological <foo>, all of the <foo> structure must be continuous. In this case, the maps corresponding to $0,1,+,-,\cdot$ all need to be continuous. ($0$ is a degenerate case: the map corresponding to $0$ is just the function from the one point set to $R$ that sends the point to $0$. Similarly for $1$)

Comment: @Hurkyl : $\:$ Additionally, (as long as there is a 1) the continuity of $-$ follows from the continuity of $\hspace{.02 in}\cdot\hspace{.02 in}$. $\hspace{.44 in}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this is that $\{0\}$ is an ideal. So if all ideals are open, then all singletons are open and in fact $R$ has the discrete topology. If you want an interesting ring, you have to use a smaller set of open ideals.

**Edit**: Ah, I misinterpreted your question. What you have written down is *not even a ring topology*, unless $R=0$. Indeed, in a topological ring, opens sets can be translated using addition. But a translate of the zero ideal in a nonzero ring is not an ideal. (Thanks to Ricky for pointing it out.)

Comment: It's "if all ideals are open, then all singletons" would have to be open to make addition continuous. $\:$ In a $\hspace{.27 in}$ non-trivial simple ring, the OP's suggested topology would not be discrete. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Dear @RickyDemer, I don't understand. In a topological ring, addition is always continuous, by definition of a topological ring.

Comment: That is why the OP's suggested topology would not necessarily make R into a topological ring. $\hspace{.84 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Ah, I see what you are saying. I interpreted OP's topology as "the ring topology generated by all ideals". Well then it's even worse, because obviously ideals cannot be translated.

Comment: What he wrote down [_is_ a topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)), since the entire space is an ideal and $\hspace{2.09 in}$ the intersection of two ideals is an ideal.

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes, but it's not a *ring topology*. That's what I should have written.

Comment: Could you prove that if all all ideals are open then all singletons are open?

Comment: What if I specify that $\{0\}$ is not included?

Comment: May I ask where a proof would fail to prove that the unions of ideals form a topo ring?  Continuity of $+$?  Because I've proved that on paper.

Comment: Dear @EnjoysMath : is $\{1\} \subseteq \mathbf Z$ a union of ideals? Obviously not. But $\{1\}$ is open in any topological ring in which $\{0\}$ is open.